# Java compare class instances using just interface methods

Tags: java

My application uses interfaces as access control in order to mask some database-specific fields from the application. For example, the `PublicFoo` interface exposes a subset of data from the `DatabaseFoo` class.

```java
public interface PublicFoo() {
  void setName(String name);
  String getName();
  void setId(String id);
  String getId();
}

public class DatabaseFoo() implements PublicFoo {
  private String name;
  private String id;

  // I want to hide this database-specific field from the PublicFoo interface that gets passed around my app. 
  private OffsetDateTime lastUpdatedTimestamp;
}
```

My question is, if I have two instances of the class `DatabaseFoo` that implement the `PublicFoo` interface, is there a way to compare these two instances using only the attributes exposed by the getters of the interface? I don't want to override the `equals()` method of `DatabaseFoo` because there are cases where I want to compare two `DatabaseFoo` objects using every field. So I think this rules out default interface methods or abstract classes.

I can accomplish what I want by writing a custom method that calls all the getters and checks for equivalency. However I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution. My fear is that if I use this approach I won't remember to update the custom method as the interface evolves in the future.

Comment: So an `equals` method that "automatically" checks the equality of both interfaces, based on all their getters? That sounds like a job for the reflection API. I'm not confident in suggesting this as an answer, as I'm not familiar enough with this API, though.

Comment: yeah something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently don't have access to an IDE, so I had to trust my memory and an online Java compiler to do this. [Here is a demo](https://paiza.io/projects/VvCQhTlRwWtVsHXNWdFLLQ).

This is an approach using reflection. It is not particularely pretty, but you can hide it with static access.

```java
public class FancyEquals {

private FancyEquals() {}

/**
 * When you ONLY evaluate getters from a shared interface
 */
public static <I, E extends I> boolean reflectiveEquals(E obj1, E obj2, Class<I> clazz) {
  return Stream.of(clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
               .filter(m -> m.getName().startsWith("get"))
               .allMatch(m -> {
                                 try{
                                   return Objects.equals(m.invoke(obj1), m.invoke(obj2));
                                 } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                                    return false;
                                 }
                               }
  );
}

/**
 * When you will evaluate ALL getters from the classes
 */
public static <E> boolean reflectiveEquals(E obj1, E obj2) {
  return Stream.of(obj1.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
               .filter(m -> m.getName().startsWith("get"))
               .allMatch(m -> {
                                try{
                                  return Objects.equals(m.invoke(obj1), m.invoke(obj2));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                                  return false;
                                }
                              }
  );
}

}
```

Do note that this is an incomplete implementation. Think, for example, that you have a `get` method with parameters (For whatever reason). The evaluation of `Method#invoke` will fail due the lack of them, although in both cases it will simply return false and log the error.

I personally don't think of this as a very elegant solution either, but is something you can hide and further tune. You may also use a specific `FancyEquals` for many special case `equals` methods (For instance, for the `Foo` entities, you could use `FooEquals#reflective` so it's more specific but equally readable. This way you could also generate an Interface for possible `XEquals` implementations and properly use generics).

Answer (score 1):

Much like overriding equals() you could use the [Comparable Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).  If your not going to override equals because of potential future breaking you probably don't want to do compareTo() either and maybe you should settle on a more simplified definition of equals for your objects. Perhaps only comparing location/connection if it is a database.

```
if ( dataBaseFooA.compareTo(dataBaseFooB) ) { ...}
```